# inserting dynamic copyright with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

`$("#footer").append("<p>&copy; 2011</p>");`

Is there a way to make the year update on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$("#footer").append( "<p>&copy; " + (new Date).getFullYear() + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use php instead ? Stick some php code that retrieves the current year in your paragraph tag and you're done ;)

Comment: What if they don't know or require server side scripting, it could just be a static HTML site.

Comment: +1 That code, btw, would be:

    &copy; <?php echo date('Y', time());  ?>;

While I love javascript it is oft used for the wrong things... and this is definitely a situation where it should be avoided.  10 years ago, everyone who wanted to do cool things did it in Flash, which just wound up breaking searchability & discoverability.  JavaScript should not be used to render every part of every Web page.  That is just a horrible design principal.

Comment: maybe page is static, without any programming or scripting language in background.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike similarly php shouldn't be used to do everything. Currently we don't even know if the OP is has a webserver which runs php, if they have any php skills. For all we know this html could sit on a network share. If they're already using jQuery why not let them use it to dynamically append the year?

Comment: @Raoul - PHP is an example.  I don't care if it is .Net, Java, Python, Perl or whatever else.  The wrong technology (in this case, client-side) is still the wrong technology.  Do not assume that the only consumer (or even the only important consumer) of anything you're building for the Web is a person sitting in front of a Web browser.  Without more information, I read this as a general question:  How do I add the year to a Web page dynamically.  The answer, emphatically, is at the server.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike clearly you are the one making assumptions here."I read this as a general question: How do I add the year to a Web page dynamically", then you're reading it wrong. "The answer, emphatically, is at the server" What if they don't have a server configured to run server side scripting, what if this page is accessed via a network share? Stop assuming and pontificating.

Comment: Anecdotally.. To my point about wrong technology -- I recently ran into this situation with a company who was developing a standard Web 2.0 App in Silverlight.  When I asked them why, they basically said that it was because they didn't know JavaScript, and my imploring them to rethink their decision was not heeded.  The results of their core technology decision has just been a fiasco on a number of levels.  This is a smaller deal, but it is the mindset that is problematic.

Comment: While it's true that we don't know whether the page sits on a server or not, I'm siding with @John here, that was the point of my remark. No JS for just a date, php makles more sense

Comment: Heh.  Apparently, this is turning into a longer discussion.

Everything we do here is assuming.  We don't have specs, we're really just guessing at any given question's intent.  If I'm pontificating and it helps people avoid errors, great...  That's why I'm here.

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner. I can't use php because the site is hosted by a company who doesn't allow access which is why I was looking for a jQuery solution.

Comment: @John thanks for clarification, the php fanboys can now rest easy.

Answer (score 2):

```
var today = new Date;
var year = today.getFullYear();
$("#footer").append("<p>&copy; "+ year + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#footer").append( "<p>&copy; " + (new Date).getFullYear() + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#footer").append( "<p>&copy; " + (new Date).getFullYear() + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
var d=new Date();  
$("#footer").append("<p>&copy; "+ d.getFullYear() +"</p>");
```